# how to convert paypal button into a react component?

Tags: reactjs, paypal

I got the following script and html for the external paypal connect button.

```html
<html>
    <head>

    </head>    
    <body>

      <span id='cwppButton'></span>
      <script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/connect/api.js'></script>
      <script>
      paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
        login.render ({
          "appid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "authend":"sandbox",
          "scopes":"openid",
          "containerid":"cwppButton",
          "responseType":"code",
          "locale":"en-us",
          "buttonType":"CWP",
          "buttonShape":"pill",
          "buttonSize":"lg",
          "fullPage":"true",
          "returnurl":"xxxxxxxxxxx.com"
        });
      });
      </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I need to add this in my react application ? any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I tried putting the script file in the index, then access it from window.paypal object.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    window.paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
      login.render ({
        "appid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "authend":"sandbox",
        "scopes":"openid",
        "containerid":"paypal-button",
        "responseType":"code",
        "locale":"en-us",
        "buttonType":"CWP",
        "buttonShape":"rectangle",
        "buttonSize":"md",
        "fullPage":"true",
        "returnurl":"xxxxxxxxxx.com"
      })
    });
  }, []);
```

then just put the **span** in the render function of my react component. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use React's [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). Place the code inside an `iframe` HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

for someone who is here for "[Connect with PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/reference/button-js-builder/)", here is the way through which you can integrate this button in reactJs, Here is the procedure.

First create custom hook to load script,

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
const useScript = url => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

then use this custom hooks

```
import useScript from 'hooks/useScript';
```

and inside the function

```
if (window.paypal) {
   paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
     login.render ({
     "appid":"REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_APPLICATION_ID",
     "scopes":"openid",
     "containerid":"cwppButton",
     "responseType":"code",
     "locale":"en-us",
     "buttonType":"CWP",
     "buttonShape":"pill",
     "buttonSize":"lg",
     "fullPage":"true",
     "returnurl":"REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_RETURN_URL"
    });
  });
}
```